# Magento2: getting error while submitting extension on marketplace

Tags: magento2, magento2marketplace

I tried to upload my Magento 2 module in Magento Marketplace while uploading the file, there was suddenly error came up and stopped to proceed.

Can anyone help with the error?

**Error:**

**"Failed to validate composer.json - demo/registration.php file is missing.,demo/etc/module.xml file is missing."**

I think I'm missing something or my extension file structure is not good. I've added composer.json on the root directory and in my module, there are five submodules.

My extension file structure is below:
[image]

Comment: Can you tell me from which directory you can create package?

Comment: I created demo directory package and tried to upload it on the marketplace.

Comment: Either you need to create from the Activation folder or sub folder like block, controller etc.

Comment: Yeah, I tried with activation and I'm able to upload it but as per our need, we have to upload all submodule in a single package.

Is there any way to upload the whole project in a single package, and do we need to change the folder and file structure?

Comment: You need to submit another package as shared one and then make main package with that one.

Comment: Hello @Ankit Singh you have solved your issues.
please share with me. I have same issue. can You confirm me? actually path of composer.json file I have composer.json file path >> app>code>vendor>module>composer.json I had uploaded zip file path >> vendor.zip>vendor>module>composer.json and other module file. I have error Failed to open file composer.json. Please verify the archive. Please help. composer.json file { "name": "renton/connector", "description": "Renton Connector (Ebay tec.)", "version": "1.0.10", "type": "magento2-module", "license": [ "OSL-3.0", "AFL-3.0" ], "require": { "php": "